# Button doesn't have ripple effect on clicking (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, android-button, android-jetpack-compose, ripple-effect

AFAIK, the buttons created with Jetpack compose should have ripple effect on clicking, by default.
But my button doesn't show ripple effect on clicking. Below is code for my button:

```
 BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(button) {
                    top.linkTo(glTopButtonProceed)
                    start.linkTo(glLeftBtn)
                    end.linkTo(glRightBtn)
                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints

                }) {

                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate("autosave_screen")
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(if (screenHeight>=700.dp)
                            50.dp
                        else
                            with(LocalDensity.current) {dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._35sdp)}) ,



                    colors = if (text.text != "" && text.text.length == 4)
                        ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green))
                    else
                        ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.gray))

                ) {
                    Text(
                        "Proceed", color = colorResource(id = R.color.dark_blue),
                        fontSize =
                        if (screenHeight>=700.dp)
                            19.sp
                        else
                            with(LocalDensity.current) {dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._12sdp).toSp()},
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_medium)),

                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                    )

                }

            }
        }
```

How do I enable ripple effect for my button?

Comment: See I am almost certain that it is because of the custom background that you are setting. The built-in ripple might not be able to infer the colour it should produce.

Comment: Does it happen when it is enabled = false?

Comment: The ripple effect appears when the background of button is gray, not when it is bright green. I think MARSK you are right.

Comment: Gabriele, ripple doesn't appear for bright green background both when enabled is true and false.

Comment: @SparshDutta it is quite strange. when the background is gray the button should be disabled.

Comment: Gabriele, I haven't used the 'enabled' parameter. My bad, I should have removed this line "enabled = (text.text != "" && text.text.length == 4)",
from question. Updating the question.

Comment: Also, I tried removing all background colors from the button. Ripple effect seems to appear only  when the button is 'non-functional', i.e doesn't meet the criteria to go to next screen. When the button is 'functional', i.e clicking on it goes to next screen, ripple effect doesn't appear.

Comment: Is this the default behaviour of Jetpack compose?

Comment: @Marsk and Gabriele, The ripple effect is produced when the color of button is gray, but not when the color of button is bright green. Is there any way to produce ripple effect even with bright green color of button?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling onClick on Button can you try to use click on Modifier click

```
modifier = Modifier .clickable(
 interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false),
    onClick = {}
        )
```

You can customise the button ripple also.

Comment: The clickable modifier doesn't work in the Button.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Box with Material Theme to get nice ripple effect

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impart specific colors to your button, try instead using `Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(...)` on the`Text` Composable instead. Don't use that `colors` parameter of `Button`.

Comment: Didn't work. 2 problems : 1. Text composable inside button didn't cover the entire  button, there was still some thick border surrounding the Text composable in button.
2. Ripple effect happened only in the surrounding thick  border